# Changing the value of a "File" parameter without creating a new instance of a class

Tags: java, file, object, parameters

I have a little problem here.

I am declaring a new object "Fleet" in these methods:

```
public void run() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File(getFile());
    Fleet fleet = new Fleet(file);
    buildFleet(file, fleet);
    }

private void buildFleet(File file, Fleet fleet) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    fleet.addVehicle(Honda);
    userMenu(fleet);

}
```

The last line calls the userMenu() method. In this method I need to be able to change the value of "File" inside Fleet without creating a new instance of the class.

```
private void userMenu(Fleet fleet) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("temp.txt");
    File file = new File("temp.txt");
    fleet = new Fleet(file);

    this.createMenu();
    choice = this.menu.getChoice();


while(choice != 8)
{
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        //Do stuff
        fleet.addVehicle(Honda);
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, I am not allowed to create any new class level data.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I changed:

```
private void userMenu() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("temp.txt");
    File file = new File("temp.txt");
```

to:

```
private void userMenu(Fleet fleet) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("temp.txt");
    File file = new File("temp.txt");
    fleet.file = file;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a setter on your `Fleet` class for the file:

```
public class Fleet {
   private File file;
   ...

   public void setFile( File file ){
     this.file = file;
   }
}
```

You can then call this method to change the file inside your fleet object by calling

```
fleet.setFile( myNewFile );
```